# Java RSS Feeds and Rome

Tags: java, rss, rome

I am trying to use Rome RSS Reader with Eclipse.

I have used BuildPath and added

```
modules-0.3.2.jar
modules-0.3.2-javadoc.jar
modules-0.3.2-sources.jar
rome-1.0.jar
rome-modules-1.0.jar



import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import com.rometools.rome.feed.synd.SyndFeed;
import com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput;
import com.rometools.rome.io.XmlReader;
```

The import com.rometools cannot be resolved.

I have found this link

[Java - Rome rss reader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285807/java-rome-rss-reader)

I have download JDom.

Which of the the Jar files do I add to the Build Path? or is it better to add them using the 'Add External Class Folder'?

Please can someone guide me to what the problem is?

I dont know of any Rome forums which may be able to assist.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your Rome version is quite old. The package names have changed since version 1.0. The imports in your code are for 1.5.0 or newer. Try with the following libraries in Eclipse project's build path:

- JDOM2: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jdom/jdom2/2.0.6
- rome: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome/1.6.0
- rome-modules: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome-modules/1.6.0
- rome-utils: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.rometools/rome-utils/1.6.0
- SLF4J API: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21